# What did Ultron mean by "You want to protect the world, but you don’t want it to change" and was it related to what he did to Strucker?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

Ultron claimed the Avengers were hypocrites for trying to protect the world without wanting to change it.

What did they he expect them to do to stop being hypocrites?

Regardless of other means Ultron has had (like gathering intelligence on a special substance he was looking for), was his treatment of Strucker also a demonstration how things should be done to actually achieve peace?

> Ultron kills Strucker (who Captain America handed over to NATO) in his cell and writes "PEACE" in Strucker's own blood. Did he try to show peace is won by not showing mercy to the opposing leaders?

If so, didn't Ultron care [Why did Iron Man give a different treatment to Dr. List?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110648/why-did-iron-man-give-a-different-treatment-to-dr-list)

Answer (score 3):

Ultron believes that humans are the problem, and thus they cannot be a part of the solution. He says:

> I know you're good people. I know you mean well. But you just didn't
> think it through. There is only one path to peace... your extinction.

According to [Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/characters/ultron/on-screen/profile):

> Ultron decides that the best way to save the Earth is to destroy all
> the people on it to make way for a new race of highly intelligent
> robotic lifeforms.

and

> When Ultron wakes up, though, he finds his creators lacking. He
> instantly makes moves to wipe the Avengers—and most of humanity—off
> the map, to evolve life on the planet to the next step.

According to at least one [Fandom](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Ultron) page, his goal is to achieve technological singularity.

Comment: But why? Just tried to understand if there was a solid reason.

Comment: I believed it's based on his character in the comics, where he wants to eliminate organic life. I'll see if I can find a helpful source

Comment: He was speaking from Thanos' mouth. This is why I think Thanos was the mastermind behind the _Age of Ultron_ events.

Answer (score -1):

A hypocrite is "someone who says they have particular moral beliefs but behaves in a way that shows these are not sincere". So The Avengers have a moral belief to protect the world, but according to Ultron, they behave in a way that shows their believes are not sincere. They don't really want to protect the world if they didn't want to change it.

Ultron's believes were, that in order to save the world, the world must change. And Avengers didn't want to change the world, so in his eyes, they were hypocrites. But in reality, he was the hypocrite, talking about saving the world, but destroying it in reality.

Comment: What was he trying to prove with Strucker? And just because he behaved like this, does it mean he was wrong about them?

Comment: @LWC I believe that by killing Strucker, he was just showing how to achieve peace, according to him.

Comment: As in stop letting the bad guys a chance to regroup? But was he right about their hyprocracy (regardless of his own)?

Comment: I don't think it was anything more, than just eliminating the bad people. Well, hypocrisy is a subjective thing, so there is no right answer if someone is a hypocrite, or not. It is for you to judge as a viewer.